# FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializer runtime expose

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

My Symfony2 API uses FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializer, with property annotations, but there are many times when I don't want to expose every property. I understand JMS has exclusion groups, but I can't figure out how to include those in my Symfony controllers. There should be a way to use PHP on a dynamic basis but that seems to be missing from the documentation too.

Comment: could you phrase a concrete question like "how to use JMSSerializer exclusion groups in a FOSRest controller?" And what do you mean by "use PHP on a dynamic basis but that seems to be missing from the documentation" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `View` class like in this [example](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md), you can set serialization context with `setSerializationContext` method

```
public function getUsersAction()
{
    $data = // get data, in this case list of users.
    $view = $this->view($data, 200)
        ->setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('list')))
    ;

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting a group, how can I add/remove fields ? Anyone knows?

Comment: You can either use groups to hide/expose certain fields according to the request, or process the entity separately and remove fields yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Since FOSRest 2.0 version you must use this:

```
$view = $this->view($response, $code);
$view->setContext($view->getContext()->setGroups(['get_client']));
```